# Issue with navbar

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been trying to solve this for the past couple of days and I just can't figure out why this is happening. So, I have a navbar which I have added my discord channel and a link to an external website with icons. I have placed it in the middle of the existing code. If I try to move it to the end of the navbar the entire website turns into a link to one of the links. Here is my code.

This is my function I created so that my discord and external link shows up.

```
function showCustomHeader ($nameOfHeader,$url){

if($nameOfHeader == "Discord"){
    echo "<a href='$url' target='_blank' title='$nameOfHeader'>";
    echo "<img style='display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle' 
src='/images/discord2.png' width='28' height='28'>";
}

if($nameOfHeader == "Equihash Pool"){
    echo "<a href='$url' target='_blank' title='$nameOfHeader'>";
    echo "<img style='display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle; margin: 
-5px;' src='/images/equihashpool.png' width='25' height='25'>";
}
}



echo '<div class="nav-wrapper">';
echo '<div class="tabmenu-out">';
echo '<div class="tabmenu-inner">';
echo '<a href="/">';
echo "<img style='display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle' 
src='/images/header.png' width='28' height='28'>";
echo '&nbsp'.YAAMP_SITE_NAME.'';
echo '</a>';
$action = controller()->action->id;
$wallet = user()->getState('yaamp-wallet');
$ad = isset($_GET['address']);
```

Then this is the rest of the code. If I move my custom headers further down near the bottom the entire on the website turns into a link and I cannot seem to figure out why...

```
showItemHeader(controller()->id=='site' && $action=='index' && !$ad, '/', 
'Home');
showItemHeader($action=='mining', '/site/mining', 'Pool');
showItemHeader(controller()->id=='site'&&($action=='index' || 
$action=='wallet') && $ad, "/?address=$wallet", 'Wallet');
showItemHeader(controller()->id=='stats', '/stats', 'Graphs');
showItemHeader($action=='miners', '/site/miners', 'Miners');
// Custom Header for Discord + Equihash pool
showCustomHeader('Discord','https://discord.gg/7cB9amA');
showCustomHeader('Equihash Pool','https://equihash.thedirtydozenpool.com');
if (YIIMP_PUBLIC_EXPLORER){
    showItemHeader(controller()->id=='explorer', '/explorer', 'Explorers');
}   

if (YIIMP_PUBLIC_BENCHMARK) {
    showItemHeader(controller()->id=='bench', '/bench', 'Benchs');
}


if (YAAMP_RENTAL) {
    showItemHeader(controller()->id=='renting', '/renting', 'Rental');
}
```

I apologise in advance if this is not formatted correctly or if I have put too much information out but I am truely stumped. Thank you for any assistance you can give me it is much appreciated./

Comment: I'm guessing you should end the anchor tags inside your if-statements?

Comment: Wow, jeeze I feel like an idiot now. Thank you very much!